# Alternative to the word reprimand?

Tags: word-choice

I looked into the dictionary for words similar to reprimand in this expression,

> I was reprimanded by the cops for reckless driving.

I checked on the web for reprimand and found lots of results, but it seems like a formal word to me(I can be wrong about this). What other words can I use for this?

**Edit**
Ok, I am sorry for the confusion,I dont really care about fine, what I wanted to ask was informal word along the line of scolding/rebkuing.

Comment: http://thesaurus.com/browse/reprimand, http://thesaurus.com/browse/criticize

Comment: *admonish, advise, berate, caution, censure, chide, counsel, ding, enjoin, exhort, forewarn, give a stern talking to, give notice, instruct, rap on
knuckles, rebuke, recommend, reprehend, reprimand, reprove, scold, slap on wrist, suggest, upbraid, urge, warn*

Comment: A reprimand is a formal warning, not a kind of criticism. So those words are not interchangeable, at least not in that sentence.

Comment: How about *warned*?

Comment: Cops only *cite* you for reckless driving; they do not merely *reprimand*.  If you wish to be ignored by the constabulary, you should go for in for wreckless driving instead.

Comment: In the UK, the "formal" word is *caution*, not *reprimand*. That's to say, if you were *cautioned by the police*, this is a formal "quasi-legal" process that [normally remains on file forever](https://www.askthe.police.uk/content/Q562.htm), and can be taken into account if you subsequently appear in court in relation to that or any other offence.

Comment: @tchrist *cite* is not used in the UK, as FF says, *caution* is used instead.

Comment: @spiceyokooko No no no.  *Cite* means you have to pay a fine, lose points on your driver’s licence, and pay more for insurance premiums.  *Caution* means you got off by the skin of your teeth, or a pretty face.

Comment: @tchrist well that's what the OP is asking for isn't it? Warned, cautioned would be more appropriate replacements for *reprimand*?

Comment: @spiceyokooko But this my point.  Reckless driving is an extremely serious charge.  You are never issued a warning for it, only ever a citation.

Comment: @tchrist Don't agree at all. In the UK you could quite easily be warned/cautioned for reckless driving/speeding just over the speed limit *without* receiving a charge for it.

Comment: @spiceyokooko Reckless driving has a formal legal definition.  It is never equivalent to speeding just over the limit. These are a billion percent different things. Only statutory DUI is worse than reckless driving. Reckless driving incurs not just fines but often loss of licence and sometimes even imprisonment. It is the strongest possible moving violation, much worse than speeding or careless driving or improper signaling or improper lane change. If you get caught driving recklessly, they have your ass. There will be no warnings, and you may be cuffed.

Comment: @tchrist Not in the UK, English isn't just restricted to *American English*.

Comment: [abuse, admonish, asperse, berate, blame, castigate, cavil, censure, chasten, chide, criticize, denounce, disparage, dress down, expostulate, give a talking-to, jump on, keep aft, lay down the law, lecture, light into, nag, objurate, preach, put down, rail, rake over the coals, rate, ream, rebuke, recriminate, reprimand, reproach, reprobate, reprove, revile, take to task, taunt, tell off, upbraid, vilify, vituperate](http://thesaurus.com/browse/scold?s=t)

Comment: @spiceyokooko Oh really? So persons guilty of driving with willful or wanton disregard for the safety of persons or property get off with a slap on the wrist in England?  Nice to know.

Comment: @tchrist Yes, sadly so. The enforcement of driving laws by the police in the UK is far more tolerant than those in North America. I'm not saying it's right, I'm just saying that's the way it is.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I wouldn't apologise for that. Statistically, UK road deaths are significantly less than US, whether you measure by numbers of [people, vehicles, or mileage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_traffic-related_death_rate). But in my experience Americans often think we drive fast in the UK, so it's probably not speed-related. Heavy-handedness on the rare occasions someone actually *does* get caught probably just makes people think the important thing is to avoid being caught, rather than to actually drive safely.

Comment: Anyway, I'm upvoting the question purely because Micheal was good enough to edit for clarification!

Comment: @tchrist: I read that as "cops only cite you for _feckless_ driving".

Answer (score 2):

Reprimand is a formal term used by the judiciary. From Oxford English Dictionary (OED):

> reprimand, n.
>
> A sharp rebuke, reproof, or censure, esp. one given by a person or body in authority; (Brit. Law) a formal or official rebuke given by a judge, magistrate, or police officer to an offender.

If you wanted an *informal* term that means the same thing, *told off* would be appropriate:

> I was *told off* by my mum for not tidying up my room.

Answer (score -1):

Reprimand is formal in nature. Hence, most synonyms (at least the ones that sound perfect in this sentence) would be formal too. The informal synonyms might sound out of place in this sentence.